# R Solution To Collapse Data By Count

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "q" = c(0,1,1,1,0),
                 "S1"=c(3,1,1,NA,NA),
                 "S2"=c(1,1,1,2,NA),
                 "S3"=c(2,2,2,3,3))
data2=data.frame("q"=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 "Value"=c(1,2,3,NA,1,2,3,NA),
                 "S1"=c(0,0,1,1,2,0,0,1),
                 "S2"=c(1,0,0,1,2,1,0,0),
                 "S3"=c(0,1,1,0,0,2,1,0))



data3=data.frame("Value"=c(1,2,3,NA),
                 "S1"=c(2,0,1,2),
                 "S2"=c(3,1,0,1),
                 "S3"=c(0,3,2,0))
```

I wish to create 'data2' and 'data3' from' data1' in a data.table approach since my data has many many rows and columns!

'data2' aggregates the counts of values in S1 S2 and S3 by value of q
'data3' aggregates the counts of values in S1 and S2 and S3 overall (ignoring q).

---

```
data1=data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "q" = c(0,1,1,1,0),
"t" = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                 "S1"=c(3,1,1,NA,NA),
                 "S2"=c(1,1,1,2,NA),
                 "S3"=c(2,2,2,3,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar option to @www's solution in `data.table` would be `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
data1_in <- melt(setDT(data1),  id.var = c("ID", "q"))[, Val := 1]
dcast(data1_in, q + value ~ variable, value.var = 'Val', 
          sum)[order(q, is.na(value))]
#   q value S1 S2 S3
#1: 0     1  0  1  0
#2: 0     2  0  0  1
#3: 0     3  1  0  1
#4: 0    NA  1  1  0
#5: 1     1  2  2  0
#6: 1     2  0  1  2
#7: 1     3  0  0  1
#8: 1    NA  1  0  0




dcast(data1_in, value ~ variable, value.var = 'Val', sum)[order(!is.na(value))]
#   value S1 S2 S3
#1:    NA  2  1  0
#2:     1  2  3  0
#3:     2  0  1  3
#4:     3  1  0  2
```

---

Or with `length`

```
data1_in <- melt(setDT(data1),  id.var = c("ID", "q"))
dcast(data1_in, q + value ~ variable, value.var = 'value',
            length)[order(q, is.na(value))]
dcast(data1_in, value ~ variable, value.var = 'value', length)[order(is.na(value))]
```

Comment: thank you!!! i updated to understand modifications necessary if this was to be done for 'q' and 't'--some exact concept but instead of group by q, groupings by combinations of q and t!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get `data2` and `data3` using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. It would be great if someone can provide a `data.table` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# This is an intermediate step to get both data2 and data3
data1_in <- data1 %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -q, values_to = "Value") %>%
  replace_na(list(Value = "NA")) %>%
  mutate(Val = 1)

data2 <- data1_in %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Val, 
              values_fill = list(Val =0), values_fn = list(Val = sum)) %>%
  arrange(q, Value) %>%
  select(q, Value, paste0("S", 1:3)) %>%
  ungroup()

data3 <- data1_in %>%
  select(-q) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Val, 
              values_fill = list(Val =0), values_fn = list(Val = sum)) %>%
  arrange(Value) %>%
  select(Value, paste0("S", 1:3)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: @akrun You are right. Thanks. I have updated my answer using `value_fn`.